# massive rename on terminal and sequentially numbered

Tags: linux, bash, rename, gnu, mv

I want to rename a lot of files (some jpg and a lot of png files) I need them sequentially numbered on each folder have this structure:

```
.../folder01
    file.png
    file.jpg
.../folder02
    file.png
    file.png
  ..........
.../folder05
    file.png
    file.png
```

and I want something like this:

```
.../folder01
    0001.jpg
    0002.png
.../folder02
    0003.png
    0004.png
  ..........
.../folder05
    0012.png
    0013.png
```

how can I make it using bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.png' \) -print  | (i=0; while read f; do 
    let i+=1; mv "$f" "${f%/*}/$(printf %04d "$i").${f##*.}"; 
done)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this works magnific! just one thing. in the case I test (folders 01 02 03) the minor numbers are in the last folder:
01 --> 0006.png 0005.png and 03 --> 0001.png 0002.png , I want the opposite.

Comment: add a `sort`:  `find` ... `-print | sort | (i=0;` ... and the files will be sorted before they get numbered, so folder01 will come before folder02, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using the automated tools of [StringSolver](https://github.com/MikaelMayer/StringSolver):

```
mv folder01/file.jpg folder01/0001.jpg
mv folder01/file.png folder01/0002.png
mv
```

The second example is needed because else it would think about renaming all files using the number in the folder's name.
The last two lines can also be abbreviated in just one, which performs the moves and immediately generalizes it:

```
mv -a folder01/file.png folder01/0002.png
```

DISCLAIMER: I am a co-author of this work for academic purposes, and working on a bash script renderer. But you can already test the system as it.