# Sequentially numbering of files in different folders while keeping the name after the number

Tags: bash, rename

I have a lot of ogg or wave files in different folders that I want to sequentially number while keeping everything that stands behind the prefixed number. The input may look like this

```
Folder1/01 Insbruck.ogg
        02 From Milan to Rome.ogg
        03 From Rome to Naples.ogg


Folder2/01 From Naples to Palermo.ogg
        02 From Palermo to Syracrus.ogg
        03 From Syracrus to Tropea
```

The output should be:

```
Folder1/01 Insbruck.ogg
        02 From Milan to Rome.ogg
        03 From Rome to Naples.ogg

Folder2/04 From Naples to Palermo.ogg
        05 From Palermo to Syracrus.ogg
        06 From Syracrus to Tropea.ogg
```

The sequential numbering across folders can be done with this BASH script that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224166/massive-rename-on-terminal-and-sequentially-numbered):

```
find .  | (i=0; while read f; do 
let i+=1; mv "$f" "${f%/*}/$(printf %04d "$i").${f##*.}"; 
done)
```

But this script removes the title that I would like to keep.

Comment: use find while read loop with -print0 | sort -z https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bash script for this job would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

argc=$#
width=${#argc}

n=0
for src; do
    base=$(basename "$src")
    dir=$(dirname "$src")
    if ! [[ $base =~ ^[0-9]+\ .*\.(ogg|wav)$ ]]; then
        echo "$src: Unexpected file name. Skipping..." >&2
        continue
    fi
    printf -v dest "$dir/%0${width}d ${base#* }" $((++n))
    echo "moving '$src' to '$dest'"
#   mv -n "$src" "$dest"
done
```

and could be run as

```
./renum Folder*/*
```

assuming the script is saved as `renum`. It will just print out source and destination file names. To do actual moving, you should drop the `#` at the beginning of the line `#   mv -n "$src" "$dest"` after making sure it will work as expected. Note that the `mv` command will not overwrite an existing file due to the `-n` option. This may or may not be desirable. The script will print out a warning message and skip unexpected file names, that is, the file names not fitting the pattern specified in the question.

Comment: This script version works very conveniently as well: one thing though: is it possible to adjust  the "%04d" - Parameter dynamically to the number of files? So that it is "%04d" for less than 10000 "%03d" for less than 1000 "%02d" for less than 100?

Comment: @PeterStrawson Yes, I edited the script for that. `argc` is the argument count and `width` is the number of decimal digits in `argc`. But this simple approach may fail if there are file names not fitting the pattern (file names which would issue the warning message in the script) in the argument list. The script may also suffer from the"argument list too long" error.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Like this, using [find](/questions/tagged/find) and perl `rename`:

```
rename -n 's@/\d+@sprintf "/%0.2d", ++$::c@e' Folder*/*
```

Drop `-n` switch if the output looks good.

With `-n`, you only see the files that will really be renamed, so only 3 files from `Folder2`.

---

## Going further

The variable `$::c` (or `$main::c` is a *package variable*) is *a little hack*  to avoid the use of more complex expressions:

```
rename -n 's@/\d+@sprintf "/%0.2d", ++our $c@e' Folder*/*
```

or

```
rename -n '{ no strict; s@/\d+@sprintf "/%0.2d", ++$c@e; }' Folder*/*
```

or

```
rename -n '
    do {
        use 5.012;
        state $c = 0;
        s@/\d+@sprintf "/%0.2d", ++$c@e
    }
' Folder*/*
```

<sub>Thanks go|dfish & Grinnz on freenode</sub>

Comment: I tested your first rename one liner without the export c=0 and it worked very well. The nice thing is that both solutions work folder-sensitive: so I can run the script on different folder names: that is very useful as the name of the folders contain the name of the works that I sequentially want to number. But there might be more than one work - lets say "Hamlet1 ... 4" and "Othello ..1..4" and like this I can run the script seperately. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> The sequential numbering across folders can be done with this BASH script that I found here:

```
find .  | (i=0; while read f; do 
let i+=1; mv "$f" "${f%/*}/$(printf %04d "$i").${f##*.}"; 
done)
```

> But this script removes the title that I would like to keep.

---

Not as robust as the accepted answer but this is the improved version of your script and just in case `rename` is not available.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ -n $1 ]] || {
  printf >&2 'Needs a directory as an argument!\n'
  exit 1
}

n=1
directory=("$@")

while IFS= read -r files; do
  if [[ $files =~ ^(.+)?\/([[:digit:]]+[^[:blank:]]+)(.+)$ ]]; then
    printf -v int '%02d' "$((n++))"
    [[ -e "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/$int${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" ]] && {
      printf '%s is already in sequential order, skipping!\n' "$files"
      continue
    } 
    echo mv -v "$files" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/$int${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  fi  
done < <(find "${directory[@]}" -type f | sort )
```

---

Now run the script with the directory in question as the argument.

```
./myscript Folder*/
```

or

```
./myscript Folder1/
```

or

```
./myscript Folder2/
```

or a `.` the `.` is the current directory.

```
./myscript .
```

and so on...

- Remove the `echo` if  you're satisfied with the output.

Comment: But this seems to contain the name of the folder within the script. And that means that one needs to change the script for every usage. M. Nejat Aydin solution allows to call the folders name while executing the script. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful comment, I have updated the answer to give the directory/path where the files are as an arguments.